# AXIOS Incoming Request Headers are converted to Lowercase in React Native

Tags: react-native, api, axios

We're are calling API using Axios and it's Header's are getting converted to lower case & API always reverted back with InvalidUser

```
export const postDataApi = (url, param, addHeader, token) => {
  let header = {};
  if (addHeader) {
    header = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    twanapikey: Config.apiKey,
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + reqparam.token,
    userID: reqparam.userID,
};
  } else {
    header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    console.log('REQUEST HEADER : ', header);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .post(url, param, {headers: header})
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          resolve(response);
        } else if (response.status == 401) {
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('EROR>>', error);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.response.status));
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          RootNavigation.navigate('Login');
          reject(error);
        } else {
          console.log('SOME  ERRO IN API MANAGER POST:', error);
          let errorResponse = convert.xml2js(error.response.data, parseConfig);
          if (errorResponse) {
            if (
              errorResponse['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][
                'soapenv:Fault'
              ]['faultstring']
            ) {
              const errormsg =
                errorResponse['soapenv:Envelope']['soapenv:Body'][
                  'soapenv:Fault'
                ]['faultstring'];
              showAlertWithCallBack(
                translate('app_name'),
                errormsg,
                translate('Ok'),
              );
              reject(errormsg);
            }
          }
        }
      });
  });
};
```

**so here when i fire the url it converts headers into lower case & we don't want to convert userID to userid it should be userID only**

```
{
  "args": {
    
  },
  "data": "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n    xmlns:taw=\"*************************************">\n<soapenv:Header/>\n<soapenv:Body>\n   <taw:doUpdateProfile>\n      <arg0>\n         <fax>123456</fax>\n         <langCode>E</langCode>\n         <mobileNumber>08347036008</mobileNumber>\n         <phone>07016799868</phone>\n         <prefCommunicationMethod>E</prefCommunicationMethod>\n         <prefLanguage>E</prefLanguage>\n         <eMail>dhara.patel@tinext.com</eMail>\n      </arg0>\n   </taw:doUpdateProfile>\n</soapenv:Body>\n</soapenv:Envelope>",
  "files": {
    
  },
  "form": {
    
  },
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "host": "postman-echo.com",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-6131ef99-32e077b02b2f302635d21552",
    "content-length": "612",
    "content-type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "authorization": "Bearer ************************",
    "userid": "Dhara Patel",
    "if-none-match": "W/\"576-DJi+oBYDjeixd5NDsWfHpQ9L3OM\"",
    "accept-language": "en-us",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "user-agent": "****************************",
    "twanapikey": "2321c6b6-8cf0-4270-8d5d-888bfbc5c463"
  },
  "json": null,
  "url": "https://postman-echo.com/post"
}
```

**This is the response we receive with error code 500**

*API Gateway encountered an error. Error Message:  Unable to invoke IS service:MobileAPIOauth.services:validateToken. Exception:Invalid User . Request Details: Service - PostLogin, Operation - doUpdateProfile, Invocation Time:12:36:49 PM, Date:Aug 31, 2021,  Client IP - 185.181.204.50, User - Default and Application:PostLogin*

**NOTE
We've already tried API interceptors, Transformers & axios-case-converter & this is also happening when we tried calling api through Fetch, XMLHttpRequest**